# invert colors on X (or xfce4)

Tags: colors, xorg, xfce

Is there a way to invert colors in X. It would be even more useful if the answer was something I could bind to a keyboard shortcut(a command and not a setting that will require a restart if X).

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: i binded that to <C-M-i> so when i can read large texts on firefox or any other program whose colors i canot invert more easily :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need the `xcalib` package:

```
xcalib -i -a
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only inverts the colors on one display.

Comment: `xcalib` supports the `-s, -screen` option that may be useful.

Comment: And to revert the inversion, just repeat the very same command.

Answer (score 2):

If you are like me and you have tried xcalib but you have encountered an error like this on debian:

```
xcalib: unsupported ramp size
```

Then you could use an alternative like: [xrandr-invert-colors](https://github.com/zoltanp/xrandr-invert-colors).

First clone the repository

```
git clone "https://github.com/zoltanp/xrandr-invert-colors.git"
```

After that you can install the build-essential package and you can compile the code with that commands:

```
sudo make deps-apt
make
sudo make install
```

After that inverting colors on the screen is simple as:

```
xrandr-invert-colors
```