# Invert colors of a single window in xfce4

Tags: colors, xfce4

Back when I was using gnome I could hit a keyboard shortcut (I think Super-M) to invert the colors of the current window, and another (Super-N?) to invert the whole screen.

I loved this as it made reading some windows much easier as I could quickly switch them to a black-background with white text.

I've since switched over to xfce4 (this is a work machine and gnome isn't supported anymore) and I'm looking for a way to get the same behavior.

I found this old question:
[invert colors on X (or xfce4)](https://superuser.com/questions/208746/invert-colors-on-x-or-xfce4)
but that seems to be just for the whole screen and I'm not sure is even relevant anymore.